# Displaying feed images via jQuery

Tags: jquery, rss, feed

I am trying to pull in some properties via jQuery from a feed, for instance,

http://feeds.nationalgeographic.com/ng/News/News_Main

I am currently using the following code:

```
    function OnLoad() {
  var mcFeed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://news.nationalgeographic.com/index.rss");
  mcFeed.setNumEntries(5);
  mcFeed.load(function(result) {
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");

      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        var attributes = ["title", "link"];
        for (var j = 0; j < attributes.length; j++) 
            {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry[attributes[j]]));
                container.appendChild(div);
            }

        }

      }
    });
  }

 google.setOnLoadCallback(OnLoad);
```

This displays the two properties in plain text; however, I want to display the associated image. It has the `<media:content>` tag. I'm new to working with feeds and I'm confused as how to access these nested tags.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using child or descendant selectors? In JQuery you can usually do stuff like `$( "div media:content" ).whatever()` or `$( "div > media:content" ).whatever()`, where the preceding word is the parent tag. Conversely, you could insert classes or ids into these child tags if there is a way to do it, and then target those.

Comment: The media:content tag is actually in the feed XML, not the HTML.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Are you creating this purely HTML or are you using PHP or Ruby (etc.) as well?